# Signing plugins - CRM C#

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

If there are more plugin classes in one Visual Studio assembly, do we have to make one signing (.snk file) for each class, or it is enough to make one signing for the whole assembly?

Also, is there any difference if i create .snk file before creating a plugin class or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a single key for each assembly. Keys can be shared between assemblies.

And no, your key can be created before your assembly is.

Comment: Thanks! I know it is not possible to create plugin before creating the assembly, but does it make any difference if i create it before plugin class?
in my case i created one plugin class, created signing key and created another plugin class, do i have to make new signing key, or old one is still valid?

Comment: Once your key is assigned to a project/assembly in Visual Studio it doesn't matter what happens to classes within that project. There's no link between the two.

Comment: You can create new or use any snk file created by VS even from another project or solution.